# shell scripting: nested subshell ++

Tags: bash, shell, nested, ksh

More than a problem, this is a request for "another way to do this".

Actually, if I want to use the result of a previous command in another one, I use:

```
R1=$("cat somefile |  awk '{ print $1 }'" )
myScript -c $R1 -h123
```

then, a "better way" is:

```
myScript -c $("cat somefile |  awk '{ print $1 }'" ) -h123
```

But what if I have to use the result several times? Let's say: using several times `$R1`, well the 2 options are:

Option 1

> R1=$("cat somefile |  awk '{ print $1}'")

```
myScript -c $R1 -h123 -x$R1
```

option 2

```
myScript -c $("cat somefile |  awk '{ print $1 }'" ) -h123 -x $("cat somefile |  awk '{ print $1 }'" )
```

Do you know another way to "store" the result of a previous command/script and use it as a argument into another command/script?

Comment: What exactly is the problem with your first suggestion? You have to correct the quoting:

`R1=$(awk '{ print $1 }' somefile)
myScript -c "$R1" -h123`

but apart from that it's fine.

Comment: option 2 is not good, since you execute external comands twice (hurrting performance) and it's not garantied that second time you'll receive the same output

Comment: You're asking for a way to store the result besides storing it in a variable?

Comment: @idimba: yes, that's why I store the result inside a variable
@Philipp, @Jefromi: I'm asking if it exists another way?, not sure about awk or sed...

Comment: For one thing, that's a useless use of `cat`. Awk accepts a filename as an argument, as **Philipp** showed but didn't really point out.

Comment: Why do you want another way? What is wrong with using a variable? That's what they're for.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there are other ways. They're just not better ways.

First, you could store the answer in a file, and then cat the contents of the file multiple times.

Second, you could pass the results to a bash function like:

```
callMyScript() {
   myScript -c "$1" -h123 -x "$1" 
}
```

invoked thusly:

```
callMyScript "$(awk '{ print $1; }' somefile)"
```

which is almost precisely identical to just saving off into a local variable.

So you're interested in using awk? You could have awk generate the line for you, and have bash run it:

```
eval $(awk '{ printf "myScript -c %s -h123 -x %s\n", $1, $1; }' somefile)
```

but now we're just getting silly, and even that's no different conceptually from simply saving off into a variable.

My advice: *Use the variable.*

Answer (score 0):

Another not perfect way:

source script #1,  then when script #2 runs all of the variables declared in #1 are available to #2.

```
#!/bin/ksh
.  myScript -c $("cat somefile |  awk '{ print $1 }'" ) -h123 
myScript2
```

Your best choice is a wrapper script that keeps all your variables for you, as everyone else already noted.

In bash the **source** builtin command is the same as the 'dot'